# Duplicating widget in UiBinder XML file

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Let's say I have Toolbar widget with buttons I'm passing in XML definition. I'd like to have the same toolbar both on top and bottom of the widget I'm creating.

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <ns:Toolbar>
        <g:Button ui:field="b1Top">1</g:Button>
    </ns:Toolbar>

    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

    <ns:Toolbar>
        <g:Button ui:field="b2Bottom">1</g:Button>
    </ns:Toolbar>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

This way I need to assign same handlers individualy for each button. Is there any way to define the toolbar in one place without creating new toolbar widget with particular widgets to show?

I hope you understand what I want to achieve. :)

Comment: You want to use the same instance of toolbar twice in your HTMLPanel?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can always create a `Ui-Binder` for your Toolbar and declare the methods and handlers for the buttons. and then use multiple instances of it.

Toolbar `ui-binder`

```
<ns:Toolbar>
    <g:Button ui:field="b1Top">1</g:Button>
</ns:Toolbar>
```

Your `ui-binder`

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <TB:Toolbar />

    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

    <TB:Toolbar />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: The thing is I will use the exact toolbar setup only twice in whole application with many similar setups.

Comment: @marines Having a ui-binder, never is wrong even if you need it twice. its basically re usability. You can at any point of time , extend it..just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you've asked, but you can set multiple widgets in the @UiHandler parameters:

```
@UiHandler( { "b1Top", "b2Bottom" } )
void onButtonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.alert("Click !");
}
```